# Skipping particular extensions in pyAesCrypt

Tags: python, file, recursion, encryption, cryptography

I have written a code which encrypts files recursively in directory

```
bufferSize = 64 * 1024
curDir = os.getcwd()
password1 = 'password'

for x in glob.glob('D:\\test\\**\*', recursive=True):
    fullpath = os.path.join(curDir, x)
    fullnewf = os.path.join(curDir, x + '.aes')
    if os.path.isfile(fullpath):
        pyAesCrypt.encryptFile(fullpath, fullnewf, password1, bufferSize)
        os.remove(fullpath)
```

It encrypts all files with all extensions in the mentioned directory, but I want it to encrypt files with all extensions except for .exe and .dll. How can I do that?

Comment: The simplest way is to check the extension at the beginning of the loop:
if x.endswith(".exe") or x.endswith(".dll"):
    continue

Comment: Thanks a lot, man! I haven't known about this method until this moment.

Comment: [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) contains the methods needed.